# Store the result of a subquery for re-use

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

Using ASP Classic and MS Access (don't ask), how can I temporarily store the result of a subquery for re-use? For example, I want to run multiple queries from my ASP script like:

```
SELECT stuff FROM (subquery) WHERE ... conditions

SELECT otherstuff FROM (subquery INNER JOIN othertable) WHERE ... different conditions
```

And display the results of each. The subquery is the same in each case, and is quite expensive to run so I would like to run it just once. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps an alternative approach would suit? You can apply filters to disconnected recordsets, so perhaps your subquery could be used as a disconnected recordset with more detailed filters applied to that set. Some notes:

```
adOpenStatic = 3
adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
adUseClient = 3

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

ssql = "SELECT * From Table1 WHERE SomeField = 'Text'"
rs.Open ssql, ocon, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

''Disconnect recordset
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

''Filter : http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_filter.asp
rs.Filter = "Code LIKE 'a%'"

Do While Not rs.EOF
    Response.Write rs.Fields("Code") & "<br>"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Filter = "Code LIKE 'c%'"

Do While Not rs.EOF
    Response.Write rs.Fields("Code") & "<br>"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I need to `JOIN` the subquery with additional tables in each query - can I do this somehow?

Comment: Not as it stands, but there may be different ways of looking at that, too. It depends to a certain extent on how much data you are looking at and whether the whole thing has a future with much more data. There is the possibility of extracting an already joined set, or of updating a new field appended to the disconnected set, and so on. It is not possible to give an alternative without more exact information.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best bet would be to insert the results of your subquery into a temporary table, then select against that table until you are done with those results.

```
INSERT INTO tmp_subQuery (col1, col2, ....) SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM... 

SELECT stuff from tmp_subQuery WHERE ... conditions
SELECT otherstuff from tmp_subQuery WHERE ... different conditions
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to explicitly drop the temporary table when I'm finished with it?

Comment: I would either do that, or empty it out (delete from tmp_subQuery) so you can re-use it again later.  Obviously, this is not something that I would recommend for a concurrent environment, but the same could be said for Access itself.

Comment: Access does not support temporary tables. Perhaps you meant a permanent / base / scratch table?

Comment: ...and if so, what effect will re-using it repeatedly have on the database file between compact and repair exercises?

Answer (score 1):

When you mean "store" do you mean physically or logically?

For physical storage, you could create a scratch table, clear it, insert the subquery results, then clear it afterwards; this will cause the database file to increase and require regular compacting. Another variation is to create a new database, create a new table, etc then drop the database when done, no file bloat problems.

However, you could logically 'save' the sunquery SQL as a [`VIEW`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-view-statement-HP001032223.aspx) to be queries multiple times:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS <subquery here>;

SELECT stuff FROM MyView WHERE <conditions here>;

SELECT otherstuff FROM MyView WHERE <different conditions here>;
```

UPDATE:

Using `CREATE VIEW` requires the engine to be in [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0) e.g. use an ADO Connection object to execute the SQL. The result of a `CREATE VIEW` statement will be a Query object in the Access UI, so if you prefer not to change the ANSI Query Mode of your UI then just create a Query object in the usual way ;)

Comment: This looks like what I am after but I can't get `CREATE VIEW` to work in Access or through my ASP script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataTable to hold the results of the subquery and use Linq to create and process the result sets for each query.

Comment: OP says ASP classic.  Linq is probably not an option.